# How to create a dependent drop-down and options in dropdown must be manageable from admin panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, dropdown

I am new in WordPress.

1) I want to create a dropdown in custom form and options in dropdown should be manageable from admin panel.

I think this can be done by creating categories and then sub-categories and sub-sub-categories but don't know how to do it in WordPress.

2) This dropdown should be dependent on each other like a country selector.

First user select from 1 then 2 will be activated and then 3rd one.

This part i can do by using Ajax.

[image: dropdown]

Kindly suggest any steps.